# HttpWebRequest UserAgent setter - This property is not implemented by this class

Tags: c#, facebook, windows-phone-7

I am developing a simple application. I am trying to implement face book in my app. I have done with a sample project. But when I try to implement in my original project I am getting error `This property is not implemented by this class.`.

```
public class FacebookLoginPageViewModel
{
    private static WebBrowser _webBrowser;
    private Page _page;
    private const string ExtendedPermissions = "user_about_me,read_stream,publish_stream,user_birthday,offline_access,email";
    private readonly FacebookClient _fb = new FacebookClient();
    private const string AppId = "1XXX58XXXXXXXX9";
    Uri url;
    public FacebookLoginPageViewModel(Panel container, Page page)
    {
        _page = page;
        _webBrowser = new WebBrowser();

        var loginUrl = GetFacebookLoginUrl(AppId, ExtendedPermissions);
        url = loginUrl;
        container.Children.Add(_webBrowser);
        _webBrowser.Navigated += webBrowser_Navigated;
        _webBrowser.Navigate(loginUrl);
    }

    private Uri GetFacebookLoginUrl(string appId, string extendedPermissions)
    {
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["client_id"] = appId;
        parameters["redirect_uri"] = "https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html";
        parameters["response_type"] = "token";
        parameters["display"] = "touch";

        // add the 'scope' only if we have extendedPermissions.
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(extendedPermissions))
        {
            // A comma-delimited list of permissions
            parameters["scope"] = extendedPermissions;
        }
        return _fb.GetLoginUrl(parameters);
    }

    void webBrowser_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        FacebookOAuthResult oauthResult;
        if (!_fb.TryParseOAuthCallbackUrl(e.Uri, out oauthResult))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (oauthResult.IsSuccess)
        {
            var accessToken = oauthResult.AccessToken;
            LoginSucceded(accessToken);
        }
        else
        {
            // user cancelled
            MessageBox.Show(oauthResult.ErrorDescription);
        }
    }

    private void LoginSucceded(string accessToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var fb = new FacebookClient(accessToken);

            fb.GetCompleted += (o, e) =>
            {
                if (e.Error != null)
                {
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
                        return;
                    });
                }

                var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)e.GetResultData();
                var id = (string)result["id"];

                LoadFacebookData(accessToken, id);
                var url = string.Format("/com/beno/WP7Client/views/FacebookLoginPage.xaml?access_token={0}&id={1}", accessToken, id);
                var rootFrame = (App.Current as App).RootFrame;
                Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                {
                    rootFrame.Navigate(new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative));
                });
            };

            fb.GetAsync("me?fields=id");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("error.."+ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

`fb.GetAsync("me?fields=id");` Here I receive error that is

```
System.NotImplementedException: This property is not implemented by this class.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetUserAgent(String value)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_UserAgent(String value)
   at Facebook.HttpWebRequestWrapper.set_UserAgent(String value)
   at Facebook.HttpWebRequestWrapper.TrySetUserAgent(String userAgent)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.PrepareRequest(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters,
  Type resultType, Stream& input, Boolean& containsEtag, IList`1& batchEtags)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.ApiAsync(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType, Object userState)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.GetAsync(String path, Object parameters, Object userState)
   at Facebook.FacebookClient.GetAsync(String path)
   at TestReactive.com.beno.WP7Client.ViewModels.FacebookViewModel.LoginSucceded(String accessToken)
   at TestReactive.com.beno.WP7Client.ViewModels.FacebookViewModel.webBrowser_Navigated(Object sender, NavigationEvPID:0ED1004E TID:0F8A0042 entArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowser.FireNavigatedEvent(Uri uri)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WebBrowserInterop.ReversePInvokeThunk.OnNavigated(Int32 webBrowserControlId, String uri)
```

I get confused. Why it is working in one project? Y it is not working in another project?
Please let me any idea to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar error when I would try to add a WebHeaderCollection to the headers. During assignment of these headers the exception. with the error message "This property is not implemented by this class," would be thrown.

**The resolution**, was in finding there was an error in the URL I gave supplied on instantiation of the WebRequest.

**IN SHORT:** A malformed URL in my web request was causing the error of "This property is not implemented by this class" to be thrown when adding headers to the collection. Fixing the URL fixed the error.

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling the catching of thrown CLR Exceptions in Visual Studio.

Under DEBUG menu Exceptions... and unchecked Common Language Run-time Exceptions.

I suspect this was disabled in your original sample project. I think the Facebook library internally catches and handles this exception so there is no need for you to break into the debugger because of it. Even if the above is unchecked and uncaught exception will still trigger the appropriate message in VS so the change in setting should be harmless.

Comment: Still getting same error. :-(. I compare with my sample project and my original project, Debug Menu=> Exceptions. Both are same.